# Fast conversion of multicolumn dataframe into dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, group-by, apply

I have the following problem. I have a pandas dataframe with columns A to D with columns A and B being kind of the identifier. My ultimate goal is to create a dictionary where the tuple (A,B) denotes he keys and the values C and D are stored under each key as numpy array. I can write this in one line if I only want to store C **or** D, but I struggle to get both under the hood. That's what I have:

```
   output_dict = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].apply(np.array).to_dict()
```

works as expected, i.e. the data per each key is a dim(N,1) array. But if I try the following:

```
   output_dict = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C','D'].apply(np.array).to_dict()
```

I receive the error that

```
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

How can I include the 2nd column such that the data in the dict per key is an array of dim(N,2).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a bit more around and next to Gerd's already helpful answer I found the following matching my needs by using lambda.

```
output_dict = df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(lambda df: np.array( [ df['C'],df['D'] ] ).T).to_dict()
```

Time comparison with Gerd's solution in my particular case:
Gerd's: roughly 0.055s
This one: roughly 0.035s

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column (e.g. `C_D`) containing lists of the corresponding values in the columns `C` and `D`. Select columns `C` and `D` from the dataframe and use the `tolist()` method:

```
df['C_D'] = df[['C','D']].values.tolist()
```

Then run your code line on that new column:

```
output_dict = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C_D'].apply(np.array).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thank you Gerd, that would also indeed solve the problem!